# How To Retrieve Columns from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

I have created two separate tables.

`Table 1 (username,email,gender,age)`

`Table 2(taskname,description,createdon,duedate,workstatus).`

Now I want to create a

`table 3 (taskname,description,createdon,duedate,staffs,workstatus)`

where staffs will show all the registered members' name and admin can select multiple users to allocate in a task. 
I am a premature php learner. 
Will anyone help me out to solve the problem,please ?

Comment: I would call this a problem, if you tried something to solve it. Right now its a requirement.

Comment: Just give me a basic idea about creating a list of users that will access from table one & on select operation they will store in table 3.

Comment: What is this `staffs` in your table 3?

Comment: It will show a list of registered users who are being registered from Table1 and stored in a database.

Comment: Your concepts are weak. Learn more about RDBMS first

Comment: I mentioned I am a premature learner,Brother. whatever it is atleast I dont sound illogical,do i ? But tbh, you just dont get my question at all. anyway, my bad & working hard to build up some STRONG concepts :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create two primary keys as user_id and task_id in table 1 and table 2 respectively. Once you are done with it, create table 3 with fields user_id and task_id as two foreign keys referencing table 1 and table 2 respectively and your requirement should get fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks a lot & I am on for it. :) Hope It will work out.